# How to add gain on playing audio from a website in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension which adds a filter on top of the audio streaming from a playing video/audio from a webpage.

So far I have am looking at the [Chrome TabCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabCapture?authuser=1) which can be used to capture media coming from the active tab. However I can not figure out how to apply a filter - distortion or gain for example - to the audio feed.